# Is my approach to installing wood subfloor over concrete correct?

Tags: concrete, subfloor, hardwood

I recently purchased a new home in South Carolina, and was planning to extend the existing hardwood throughout the rest of the ground floor. Once I began to remove the existing carpet, I saw that there's no wood subfloor: the existing floor is glued to the concrete.

[image: Image of concrete foundation with existing hardwood]

I want to use 3-1/2 in. hardwood flooring (not engineered), so in this situation my plan would be to:

1. Remove the existing hardwood
2. Install a vapor barrier on top of the concrete
3. Lay down 3/4 in. plywood and secure it to the concrete
4. Install a felt pad on top of the plywood
5. Install the new hardwood

I haven't dealt with a scenario like this before, so I just want to be sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't step 1 be: *Remove the existing **carpet** ?* Or do you mean: Remove the rest of the floor that already **is** hardwood, as well as the carpet? I'm confused...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I meant removing the existing carpet and hardwood. I originally intended to extend the existing hardwood floor, but given that it's glued and there are areas where the adhesive is lifting and there are visible gaps between some boards (house was built in 2003 and hasn't been renovated at all), I figured it may be easier just to take everything up and start fresh. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why would you add a layer of plywood on the concrete?  Are you wanting to do a nail down installation?  I don't see any advantage to a putting down the plywood.  Gluedown is probably the most premium of the installation techniques.

Comment: "house was built in 2003". Ha! laughs my house, built in the 1890s... Sure, 20 years is enough life out of carpet, but man, if that's how long a hardwood floor lasts these days, they _really_ don't build 'em like they used to!

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Someone much more experienced than myself explained to me that gluing hardwood (not engineered hardwood) isn't recommended due to the characteristics of wood, and that a nail down installation, when done correctly, would be the safest bet.

Comment: That is true, solid hardwood is not recommended to be laid directly on top of concrete.  There are engineered floors that are rated for concrete installation, and honestly that would be my first choice.  Look at all the doors and trim in the area and see if it would be OK to raise the floor 2".  It's a big job.

Comment: @JPhil1618, where does this "not recommended" to be laid directly on top of concrete come from - are you just talking about having a moisture break?  The NWFA - National Wood Flooring Association - install guide doesn't seem to have any recommendation against doing glue down on concrete.  
https://pacifichardwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/NWFAInstallGuide2019.pdf

Comment: What is the purpose of the "felt pad", and why place it on top of the plywood?

Comment: @r13 From what I've been told, the felt underlayment helps deaden the sound creating by walking on the hardwood. Without it, the sound would be more pronounced due to wood on wood acoustics. The felt underlayment also offers some moisture protection, though moisture shouldn't be an issue given that a vapor barrier would be installed beneath the plywood.

Comment: The main source of noise is from the nail due to the volume change of the flooring. You can't avoid it if the wood wasn't properly dried, and humidity in the room wasn't maintained. I don't think the felt pad is such a good idea, which may create uneven spaces between the hardwood finish and the subfloor like the sponge. If moisture is a concern, even minor, the felt pad shall be placed on top of the concrete then.

Comment: @r13 As long as a vapor barrier exists between the concrete and plywood, simply nailing the hardwood to the plywood with no underlayment should suffice? That would definitely save some time.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - after you do core samples and humidity checks, sure, you can glue. See pages 67~69."Do not install flooring over any issues without first addressing them with the builder, concrete contractor, architect, homeowner, or any other responsible party, prior to preparing the subfloor for new flooring. Many stress cracks, hollow spots, or crumbling areas may be an indication of structural issues, geographic soil conditions, or poor quality concrete that should be addressed by a professional." That's the *CYA* fine print right there.

Comment: I think that is sufficient if the concrete floor is well prepared and be level. If not, a felt layer will help to eliminate the gaps between the plywood subfloor and the concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a couple of steps:

- Remove all baseboard trim
- Cut door trim to clear new subfloor/floor
- Adjust any other "things" like baseboard heat/radiators to sit higher (as appropriate)
- Reinstall all baseboard trim

I'm not saying you shouldn't do this, but there are other things to consider when you're raising the floor by 3/4" plywood subfloor, the thickness of the felt pad and the thickness of the flooring itself (3/4" minimum, I'd think, probably more).

I'd agree that a *real* hardwood floor will outlast and out shine any fake "hardwood" floor, no matter how much they emphasize "luxury" in the vinyl plank, but there will be a bit more work.

Comment: I appreciate the "accept" check mark, but you may want to wait to see if anyone else chimes in...